# Why is MEF composition not working?

Tags: c#, mef, composition

I have declared the collection:

```
[ImportMany]
IEnumerable<ServiceDivision> ServiceDivisions { get; set; }
```

I call `DoComposition` in the constructor, straight after `InitializeComponent`:

```
private void DoComposition()
{
    var divisionCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettingsKeys.ServiceDivisionsPath], "*.dll");
    var container = new CompositionContainer(divisionCatalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

Yet after calling this, `ServiceDivisions` has zero elements. I've used this same pattern in two other projects and it works.  A breakpoint and watch tell me `divisionCatalog` has 3 loaded files and 4 parts. Each part is declared much like:

```
[Export(typeof(ServiceDivision))]
[SectionUIMetadata(MenuText = "System Configuration")]
internal class ConfigDivision : ServiceDivision
{
}
```

I fail to see why these parts are not imported into `ServiceDivisions`; they are loaded in the catalogue and they are of the correct type. What could be wrong?

Comment: Is SectionUIMetadataAttribute a custom MEF export metadata? Perhaps it is causing some conflict. Have you used Mefx (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576068.aspx) to check for composition failures?

Comment: What version of MEF are you using?